# Swift: Prevent flicker when presenting login screen at startup

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

We have two storyboards in our app.  The default view in storyboard #1 assumes the user has previously supplied valid credentials.  If they have not done so we "redirect" to the login screen in storyboard #2:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentication", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as UIViewController
presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works - but there is a flicker when this code runs where the default view briefly appears prior to the login view being displayed.  How can you perform this action without a flicker?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of presenting LoginController you have to set the respective ViewController as rootviewcontroller to the window in **Appdelegate** itself as folllows:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
//Check for credentials,if value available make LoginStatus as true
if LoginStatus == true{
    //Change Storyboard name "Main" to your "storyboard #1" name.
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //Change Viecontroller name "My_Offer" to your "DefaultViewController name" name.
    let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("My_Offer") as UIViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
}else{
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentication", bundle: nil)
    let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as UIViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
}
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This will prevent from displaying default view before presenting LoginController.

Or else

In storyboard #1 create a DummyViewController(UIViewController) and make it as **InitialViewController** and set a Background image(**Your SplashScreen Image**) to DummyViewController .In viewdidload check for credentials,If You have value

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard #1", bundle: nil)
let controller =     storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("default view ") as    UIViewController
presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if no credentials go with your given code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentication", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as   UIViewController
presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this too prevents flicker but it is not good way to do.I suggest **First Method** setting rootviewcontroller.This may help you.Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to set launch screen `viewcontroller` as `rootviewcontroller` of the application until the all your deciding factor get executed. This is one of the finest approach for async operation.